# hibernate SessionFactory does not work

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

i have a problem with hibernate but i don't understand what is this problem exactly
if you have an idea?

```
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Customer> listCustomer() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("FROM customer").list();
}
```

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    CustomerDaoImpl dao=new CustomerDaoImpl();

    for(int i=0; i<dao.listCustomer().size(); i++){
        System.out.println(i);
    }   
   }
 }
```

**error**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.apps.dao.CustomerDaoImpl.listCustomer(CustomerDaoImpl.java:37)
at com.apps.dao.Main.main(Main.java:8)
```

Comment: You have add sessionFactory to class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must initialize your `sessionFactory`. In earlier hibernate versions you did it like this

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

Since version 4.3.0. you have to do this

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().
applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
```

Comment: @Predag Maric thnx it's working but it return another error : (Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer])

Comment: Check if you have a default no-arg constructor in `Customer` class. `public Customer() { super(); }`